# Does Salesforce Developer Edition support AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, email-template

I am completely new to Salesforce, though I am an experienced software developer. I have a Salesforce Developer Edition account and am attempting to created a simple test scenario that includes AMPscript.

I have created a custom HTML email template and included some very simple AMPscript. Basically, "hello world" but no matter what I've tried, Salesforce does not interpret the AMPscript code at all, either in a preview, test email send, or anywhere else. The emails is sent, but the AMPscript code is plainly visible.

My question is, is this even supposed to work? Does the Developer Edition even support AMPscript? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I don't think Salesforce developer edition support AMPscript. You might need a Marketing cloud org to use that.

Comment: Hi Tom,
Have you connected salesforce dev org and marketing cloud using connector? or are you using old developer orgs of Markeitng cloud .From where are you sending email?. Can you please paste your ampscript here?

Answer (score 0):

If your emails are being sent via Marketing Cloud, then, yes, AMPScript will work.

You'll need to utilize the [**Marketing Cloud Connector**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/) as [**@kalpesh**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/29045/kalpesh) suggested.